# Converting Base 64 data into decimal data

Tags: python, base64

I've been trying to convert files from their hexidecimal form to base64 form so that they are more compressed and are easier to transfer.

However, as I'm trying to use Fast Fourier Transform in Python to transfer the information, I need to work with purely numeric data rather than a mixture of letters and numbers.

Is there a way to convert from base64 to some kind of numeric data, either decimal or anything else that takes up the least amount of space? Or is there an alternative that allows me to convert the file data straight into a numeric form?

Edit:
My code follows something like this:

```
import base64
import os

file = os.path.join('file.jpg')
image = open(file, 'rb')
image_read = image.read()
image_64_encode = str(base64.b64encode(image_read))
```

I've taken a jpg file and taken its file's reading binary data, which I want to encode in a way that allows me to send over sound waves, much like frequency modulation. This will allow me to send data from one device to another.

The code above gives me a long string of alphanumeric characters that does not allow me to plot the data in this form in the xy plane, which I want to do as I want to apply inverse fourier transform on the numbers to create a sound wave from it.

Is there a way to convert the base 64 string into one long concatenated string of just purely digits that still represents the same data?

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't fully understand what you really want to do. But with ord() you can get an integer which represents a unicode charachter. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

Comment: Converting from binary to base64 does not compress your data: it *inflates* it. Each 6-bit block is replaced by an 8-bit ASCII printable character. The purpose is to encode arbitrary data into plain text in a way that text-based protocols can handle safely.

Comment: One of the smallest way to do it would be to **not** convert the numeric data to base64. Just save it in a binary file. You can read the data back in using the `struct` module. Another compact alternative would be the `array` module. To compress the data there's always the `gzip` module.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need to use base 64 at all. What's in `image_read` after the `image.read()` call is *binary data* (i.e. the .jpg file's contents). You can interpret that data as a series of 1, 2, 4, or 8 byte integers  by "unpacking" that data into a list of integer values using the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module in the standard library.